# How to make dynamically created views line up vertically?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout. The button "go" is added with XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#0099FF"
    android:text="go"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

And the checkboxes dynamically:

```
for (final String str : strs) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    cb.setText(str);
    cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    thisll.addView(cb);
}
```

Currently elements line up horisontally:
[image]

How to make them line up vertically?

Comment: Nope, i'll try it out

Comment: did you make "orientation"= vertical in xml file of linear layout?

Comment: yup, android:orientation="vertical" in <LinearLayout> worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `orientation="vertical"` to your LinearLayout?


Eg.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- The things you want aligned vertically go here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to put this sort comment like answers in comment section only.

Comment: I disagree, most people scroll down to the answer section to find the solution to the problems they're having. If the answer is in the comments they won't see it, don't you think?